# Nav bar doesn't extend to the 100% of the webpage when using a video as a background

Tags: html, css, web, nav

My navigation bar doesn't reach the left end of the screen, only the right end. This issue only came up when I tried to put a video as a background for the web page.

I tried setting the padding to 0, keeping in mind that that would put the text at the start and the end of the navbar, but it didn't work out.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
}

#myVideo {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.content {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  height: 80px;
  background: #29282e;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0rem calc((100vw - 1300px) / 2);
  user-select: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.logo {
  color: #b4b4b4;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  animation: ripple 2s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes ripple {
  from {
    color: #b4b4b4;
  }
  to {
    color: #5f5f5f;
  }
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #5f5f5f;
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

nav a span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

nav a span:after {
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

nav a:hover span {
  padding-right: 10px;
}

nav a:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}

.title {
  user-select: none;
}

.title-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  height: 95vh;
  padding: 3rem calc((100vw - 1300px) / 2);
}

.column-left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  color: #b4b4b4;
  padding: 0rem 2rem;
}

.column-left h1 {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  font-size: 5rem;
}

.column-left p {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

button {
  padding: 1rem 3rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border: none;
  color: #5f5f5f;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.button {
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: none;
  color: #5f5f5f;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}

.button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button span:after {
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}

.column-right {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0rem 2rem;
}

.title-image {
  width: 50%;
  transition: transform 0.7s ease-out;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .title-container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
    <source src="media/background.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<div class="content" width="100%">
  <nav>
    <div class="logo">wonder〇</div>
    
    <div class="nav-items">
      <a href="/"><span>about</span></a>
      <a href="/"><span>contact</span></a>
      <a href="../login/login.html"><span>login</span></a>
    </div>
  </nav>
  
  <section class="title">
    <div class="title-container">
      <div class="column-left">
        <h1>wondersphere</h1>
        <p>explore interactive and playful virtual museums.</p>
        <button class="button"><span>get started</span></button>
      </div>
      
      <div class="column-right">
        <img src="media/title_img.png" alt="" class="title-image" id="titleImage" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour] to learn how to respond to answers. "Thanks" comments are discouraged.

Comment: Are you familiar with using your browser's document inspector? It makes finding issues like this trivial.

Comment: as isherwood said you can easily solve these kind of issues using your devtools Elements and Styles

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the padding in .content:20px

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
}

#myVideo {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
  }

.content {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: #f1f1f1;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    /* padding: 20px; */
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
    height: 80px;
    background: #29282e;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0rem calc((100vw - 1300px) / 2);
    user-select: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.logo {
    color: #b4b4b4;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0 2rem;
    animation: ripple 2s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes ripple {
    from {
        color: #b4b4b4;
    }
    to {
        color: #5f5f5f;
    }
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #5f5f5f;
    padding: 0 1.5rem;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

nav a span{
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

nav a span:after {
    content: '\00bb';
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: -20px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

nav a:hover span {
    padding-right: 10px;
}

nav a:hover span:after {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 0;
}

.title {
    user-select: none;
}

.title-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    height: 95vh;
    padding: 3rem calc((100vw - 1300px) / 2);
}

.column-left {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    color: #b4b4b4;
    padding: 0rem 2rem;
}

.column-left h1 {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    font-size: 5rem;
}

.column-left p {
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

button {
    padding: 1rem 3rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    border: none;
    color: #5f5f5f;
    background: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 50px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

.button {
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: none;
    color: #5f5f5f;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 5px;
}
  
.button span {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
  
.button span:after {
    content: '\00bb';
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: -20px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
  
.button:hover span {
    padding-right: 25px;
}
  
.button:hover span:after {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 0;
}

.column-right{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0rem 2rem;
}

.title-image{
    width: 50%;
    transition: transform 0.7s ease-out;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .title-container {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
    <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
        <source src="media/background.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <div class="content" width="100%">
        <nav>
            <div class="logo">wonder〇</div>
            <div class="nav-items">
                <a href="/"><span>about</span></a>
                <a href="/"><span>contact</span></a>
                <a href="../login/login.html"><span>login</span></a>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <section class="title">
            <div class="title-container">
                <div class="column-left">
                    <h1>wondersphere</h1>
                    <p>explore interactive and playful virtual museums.</p>
                    <button class="button"><span>get started</span></button>
                </div>
                <div class="column-right">
                        <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300" alt="" class="title-image" id="titleImage"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
```

Comment: You are very welcome. That is coding sometimes we don't find simple things lol! Glad that it helped.